# Removing an element from a list by index without returning the deleted element

Tags: python

simply put, I just want an alternative to `.pop` that does not return the removed element and also takes an index for parameters.
To give an example, I enter this code:

```py
[1, 2, 3].pop(0)
```

but it gives me this as an output:

```py
[1]
```

what I want as an output is `[2, 3]` and not `[1]`.
is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [`del`](https://www.csestack.org/difference-between-remove-del-pop-python-list/)?

Comment: @bluecouch what if I wanted to use a method? I know that realistically using a keyword would probably work but hypothetically what if I had to use a method?

Answer (score 2):

you should use the remove() method but it takes an element as an argument not an index if you want to use an index try this

```py
test = [1, 2, 3]
test.remove(test[0])
```

the output should be
`[2, 3]`

Comment: "remove" doesn't return anything, thus it will solve the problem of not returning popped element but wont solve the problem of getting updated list in output.

Comment: `Remove the first item from the list whose value is equal to x. It raises a ValueError if there is no such item.` So it might not work as expected if the same value appears multiple times.

Comment: I think he didn't mention the problem of getting an updated list. He just didn't want a returned element.
In that case, use copy() to create a new list then use remove() to the list we just copy.

Answer (score 1):

If you store the list `[1, 2, 3]` inside a variable say `test`, apply pop on that variable and then print the variable you would get the desired results

```
test = [1, 2, 3]
test.pop(0)
print(test)
```

Output -

```
[2, 3]
```

Comment: Yea printing the array while applying the `.pop()` method to it directly will output what the `.pop()` method is returning instead of the array's new value.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use list slicing method.

```
print([1,2,3][1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

`del` command is what you're looking for. For more information: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types

```py
a = [1, 2, 3]
del a[0]
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override defination of pop or create a user defined function, something like below.

```
def pop_and_remove(index, arr):
    arr.pop(index)
    return arr
```

Now call pop_and_remove(0, arr) this will return updated arr.